# Image Registration + Banded Images

Tags: python, image, opencv, homography, ransac

I am currently working on a image registration / image alignment problem. To illustrate the problem let us assume that there is a shift in the image pixels.

Currently i have tried the following methods:

- Feature extraction using SURF
- Apply Homography + RANSAC

Even then there is a mis-alignment with the images, due to the banding of the images. I would like to address if there is anyway we can correct the banding of the images to align in a proper manner.

Banded Image - pixel shift
[image]

Reference Image
[image]

Currently I am using `OpenCV and Python` to do the analysis.

Comment: The main methods for image alignment are global, not local alignments. They seek to find the best transformation matrix to warp the whole image. You can use dense optical flow estimation algorithms to find the flow of individual pixels and warp those, but a lot of aftercare is necessary if you don't consider neighboring pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, are there any references or examples of which i can refer back. I am pretty new to Optical flow algorithms, henceforth any examples or references in relation to opencv would be helpful.

Comment: I have only implemented them manually, so I can't give a good answer on methods from any particular library. I know OpenCV has [dense flow methods](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/optflow/doc/dense_optflow.html) but I've never used them; maybe you can find a tutorial.